# Responsive WordPress Themes

Tags: wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

Does anyone know of any responsive wordpress themes where I will have a great deal of control over the CSS and structure of the website? I want all of the functionality of wordpress like the blogging features, but I want to have total control over design and implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of my favorite starter themes are: http://themble.com/bones/ and http://underscores.me/

You can look at frameworks like: http://themeshaper.com/thematic/ or http://my.studiopress.com/themes/genesis/

You can always grab any theme you like, and create a child theme: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: I think bones is what I'm going with

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of the new ones have this functionality for you. Especially ones that include Visual Composer - a drag and drop feature. If you want to hardcode CSS, most themes have options to include CSS specifically for the page or for the website in general in its own Theme Options (this is assuming you don't want to edit styles.css in editor).

Answer (score 0):

I think you must go for "Avada" wordpress responsive multipurpose theme which let you customize many of the options from its backend only.

**URL:** [Avada | Responsive Wordpress Multipurpose Theme](http://themeforest.net/item/avada-responsive-multipurpose-theme/2833226)